# SQL Stored Procedure works fine in SQL Server Management Studio, but not in Reporting Services (SSRS)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, reporting-services

I have a procedure that is supposed to build a report in SSRS with numbers for a list of people where column A is their name, column B and C are their numbers thus far this year (from January and up to for example May), and column D and E are the same numbers from the previous year in the same span of months. Below is what the procedure looks like. Also; I've altered the names and key data here to make it more understandable for you, but that might mean that there is a slight typo here and there that I don't immediately spot. Examples of what the parameter data may be are put as a commented out line below each parameter.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[number_comparison]
    @resource AS int
    -- retrieves a specific employee, or NULL. NULL on this parameter will retrieve a list of all employees (or all within a given type if the employee_type parameter is set)
    ,@employee_Type AS nvarchar(20)
    -- type will retrieve all employees of a certain type. NULL on this will retrieve all employees regardless of type
    ,@time AS nvarchar(6)
    -- Comes in the form YYYYMM. Cannot be NULL.
AS 
BEGIN

DECLARE @time_last_year nvarchar(6) = CONVERT(nvarchar(6), @time-100);

SELECT 
    fk_resource
    ,SUM(amount) AS sum_amount_last_year
    ,AVG(amount) AS avg_amount_last_year
INTO 
    #lastyearsnumbers
FROM
    datamart.numbers_month
INNER JOIN 
  dvh.resources
  ON
    (resources.pk_resource = fk_resource)
  AND
    (resources.pk_ressurs != -1)
WHERE
  (fk_time LIKE LEFT(@time_last_year,4)+'%')
AND
  (@resource IS NULL OR fk_resource = @resource)
AND
  (@employee_Type IS NULL OR employee_Type = @employeeType)
AND
  (fk_time < ((@time_last_year)+1))
GROUP BY
  fk_resource

SELECT
  fk_resource
  ,name
  ,SUM(amount) AS sum_amount_this_year
  ,AVG(amount) AS avg_amount_this_year
  ,TEMP.sum_amount_last_year
  ,TEMP.avg_amount_last_year
FROM
  datamart.numbers_month 
INNER JOIN 
  dvh.resource
  ON
    (resource.pk_resource = fk_resource)
  AND
    (resource.pk_resource != -1)
LEFT OUTER JOIN
  #lastyearsnumbers TEMP
  ON TEMP.fk_resource = datamart.numbers_month.fk_resource
WHERE
  (fk_time LIKE (LEFT(@time,4))+'%')
AND
  (@resource IS NULL OR fk_resource = @resource)
AND
  (@employee_Type IS NULL OR employee_Type = @employee_Type)
AND
  (fk_time < (@time+1))
GROUP BY
  fk_resource, name, TEMP.sum_amount_last_year, TEMP.avg_amount_last_year

END;
```

The point of this task is that it should be possible to retrieve a report for a given month of a year and see what the accumulated numbers from january of that year and up to the selected month is, and compare it to the same period from the year before.

It uses a Left Outer Join because some employees are new and do not have any numbers from last year.

When I execute this procedure in SQL Server Management Studio, it runs completely fine. I get all the right data and a list of employees that also include the new employees that have no data for last year.

When I execute the procedure in SSRS, I get a list of employees that *only* cover the employees that have data both for this year as well as last year. It is almost as if the left outer join is run as an inner join.

What could cause this?

Comment: On the lower query you're using `fk_resource` without aliases on `WHERE ` and `GROUP BY`. Is that working?

Comment: @vercelli you spotted some of the mistakes I made when renaming everything to make it more understandable to you guys. Thank you for pointing it out. Should be corrected now.

Comment: OK, but the problem reamains: `GROUP BY
  fk_resource, name, TEMP.sum_amount_last_year, TEMP.avg_amount_last_year`

Comment: As far as I know; alias is not required to make a query work. And like I said; this runs fine in SQL Server Management Studio. It also runs without error in SSRS. It is just the joined data that is incorrect.

Comment: But in `GROUP BY fk_resource` belongs to `#lastyearsnumbers` or to `datamart.numbers_month`?

Comment: I see what you mean now! It worked fine in SQL Server Management Studio so I didn't consider that this might be interpreted differently when run through SSRS. I specified all values and what table they might belong to, and that seemed to fix the problem! Thank you!

Comment: Nice to hear that ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @vercelli for pointing out that I hadn't specified exactly which tables the group by parameters pointed to. SQL Server Management Studio natively understood which tables where the right one, but when run through SSRS this seemed to get screwed up. I gave the tables alias names and specified the tables on the parameters using the aliases and that seemed to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I remember reading it somewhere (can't remember on top of my head), Report Wizard doesn't like temp tables. I will update the comment when I get it. But, in the mean time, can you try running the same query by using CTE (common table expression) instead of temp tables or using any staging tables?

I amended your script to use CTE, as below.

```
    ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[number_comparison]
        @resource AS int
        -- retrieves a specific employee, or NULL. NULL on this parameter will retrieve a list of all employees (or all within a given type if the employee_type parameter is set)
        ,@employee_Type AS nvarchar(20)
        -- type will retrieve all employees of a certain type. NULL on this will retrieve all employees regardless of type
        ,@time AS nvarchar(6)
        -- Comes in the form YYYYMM. Cannot be NULL.
    AS 
    BEGIN

    DECLARE @time_last_year nvarchar(6) = CONVERT(nvarchar(6), @time-100);

    WITH cte AS
    (
        SELECT 
            fk_resource
            ,SUM(amount) AS sum_amount_last_year
            ,AVG(amount) AS avg_amount_last_year
        FROM
            datamart.numbers_month
        INNER JOIN 
          dvh.resources
          ON
            (resources.pk_resource = fk_resource)
          AND
            (resources.pk_ressurs != -1)
        WHERE
          (fk_time LIKE LEFT(@time_last_year,4)+'%')
        AND
          (@resource IS NULL OR fk_resource = @resource)
        AND
          (@employee_Type IS NULL OR employee_Type = @employeeType)
        AND
          (fk_time < ((@time_last_year)+1))
        GROUP BY
          fk_resource
    )
    SELECT
      fk_resource
      ,name
      ,SUM(amount) AS sum_amount_this_year
      ,AVG(amount) AS avg_amount_this_year
      ,TEMP.sum_amount_last_year
      ,TEMP.avg_amount_last_year
    FROM
      datamart.numbers_month 
    INNER JOIN 
      dvh.resource
      ON
        (resource.pk_resource = fk_resource)
      AND
        (resource.pk_resource != -1)
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
      cte as TEMP
      ON TEMP.fk_resource = datamart.numbers_month.fk_resource
    WHERE
      (fk_time LIKE (LEFT(@time,4))+'%')
    AND
      (@resource IS NULL OR fk_resource = @resource)
    AND
      (@employee_Type IS NULL OR employee_Type = @employee_Type)
    AND
      (fk_time < (@time+1))
    GROUP BY
      fk_resource, name, TEMP.sum_amount_last_year, TEMP.avg_amount_last_year

    END;
```

Comment: You're right; SSRS doesn't like temp tables, which is why this was done using a stored procedure. A comment made by @vercelli on my original question had the solution though!